# Tune when sssd goes into offline mode

Tags: optimization, sssd

I have a linux server with sssd using an ldap server for the auth backend.  The connection to the ldap server is flakey, so I get authentications which are fine and then suddenly one will take forever and timeout, only to be fine the next time it tries.

I'm trying to tune sssd to use the cache more often and quicker.  I understand that sssd uses caching in both offline and online modes, but I suspect it's trying to use online mode more than is optimal for my situation.

- How does sssd decide when to go offline and come back online?
- How can I tune how quickly it transitions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

reconnection_retries (integer)
Number of times services should attempt to reconnect in the event of a Data Provider crash or restart before they give up
Default: 3

Reduce to 1 and look at the behavior of the

Comment: So, "services" in this case is nss or sudo, and if sssd tries to connect to the back end reconnection_retries times, sssd flips into offline mode?

Comment: Yes, if cache_credentials = true. When sssd flips into offline mode he use cache.